# Meteor server methods not working on iOS simulator or xCode

Tags: ios, meteor

I am having an issue with the server methods not working on my Meteor app. I run:

```
meteor run ios-device
```

and get an xCode project, but the server side methods don't work. When I run the simulator:

```
meteor run iOS
```

the server side methods don't work either.

The server methods work fine in my browser. Why?

The packages that I have installed are:

```
accounts-facebook                        1.0.4  Login service for Facebook ac...
accounts-google                          1.0.4  Login service for Google acco...
accounts-twitter                         1.0.4  Login service for Twitter acc...
cordova:com.google.cordova.admob         2.7.4
cordova:org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser  0.5.1
fourseven:scss                           2.1.1  Style with attitude. Sass and...
http                                     1.1.0  Make HTTP calls to remote ser...
iron:router                              1.0.7  Routing specifically designed...
meteor-platform                          1.2.2  Include a standard set of Met...
meteoric:ionic                           0.1.17  Ionic components for Meteor....
meteoric:ionic-sass                      0.1.9  Ionic's CSS Framework in SASS...
meteoric:ionicons-sass                   0.1.6  Ionic's Ionicons library in S...
service-configuration                    1.0.4  Manage the configuration for ...
u2622:persistent-session                 0.3.3  Persistently store Session da...
urigo:angular                            0.8.4  The simplest no-conflict way ...
```